# Wordpress: get attachments, but not post-thumb

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have the following code in my **functions.php**:

```
function get_images($size = 'thumbnail') {

global $post;
return get_children( array('post_parent' => get_the_ID(), 'post_status' => 'inherit', 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'order' => 'ASC', 'orderby' => 'menu_order ID') );

}
```

And in my **single.php**

```
<?php $photos = get_images('full'); ?>

            <?php $x = 0; ?>
            <?php foreach($photos as $photo): ?>
                <?php if($x < 1): ?>
                    <img src="<?=wp_get_attachment_url($photo->ID)?>" alt="fullImg" /> 
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php $x++;
                 ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
```

I want to show just ONE image there, but it shows me also the **post-thumb image, which I don't want**, is there an option to exclude that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's some crazy coding there! It's pointless accepting a size in your function, because it merely returns an array of post objects.

Once you've got your posts, *then* use the appropriate attachment function(s) to get the information on the attachment size you're after.

I would propose a function like this instead;

```
function get_images($overrides = '', $exclude_thumbnail = false)
{
    return get_posts(wp_parse_args($overrides, array(
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'post_parent' => get_the_ID(),
        'post_type' => 'attachment',
        'post_mime_type' => 'image',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'exclude' => $exclude_thumbnail ? array(get_post_thumbnail_id()) : array(),
        'orderby' => 'menu_order ID'
    )));
}
```

And putting it in practice;

```
<?php if ($photo = get_images('numberposts=1', true)): ?>

    <img src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url($photo[0]->ID); ?>" alt="fullimg" />

<?php endif; ?>
```

UPDATE: Typo in function - fixed.